# Need help on groovy syntax

Tags: grails, groovy

I came across a groovy syntax that creates a link in gsp file like this:

```
class LoginTagLib {
def loginControl = {
out << """[${link(action:"login",controller:"user"){"Login"}}]"""
}}
```

I know that it will eventually turned into this in html:

```
<a href="/racetrack/user/login">Login</a>
```

---

However, there are 2 portion of the syntax that I don't understand:

1. I don't understand `${link(action:"login",controller:"user"){"Login"}}`:

   - I get the `$()`, which is used for string interpolation.
   - I get the `link(action:"login",controller:"user")` too, just 2 arguments passed into `link`
   - but what is the `{"Login"}` doing behind?
2. I don't understand the `"""[ ]"""` that is used to enclose the whole thing, I tried to take away a pair of `"`, but it wounldn't work anymore. So it proves to me it has it's significance.

Anybody help to shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In groovy if the last argument of a function is a closure you can you change this syntax `foo(arg1, arg2, ..., { ... })` to `foo(arg1, arg2, ...) { ... }`. this is what happens here, the last argument of `link()` is a closure that should evaluate to the textual representation of the link
2. ''' and ''' allow for multi-line string. """ """ are the same but also support variable substitution